# GoldenGate Hub Pattern for replication from Oracle to MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, database-migration

I have no experience with Oracle GoldenGate, so any information would be appreciated.

I found this [old blog post](https://jinyuwang.weebly.com/for-mysql/oracle-goldengate-for-mysql-is-certified-on-amazon-aurora-database) about remote capture/delivery (GoldenGate Hub pattern) of Oracle GoldenGate for MySQL, but I am assuming this is about homogeneous migration, MySQL to MySQL.

Am I correct or is it also possible between heterogeneous migration, e.g, from on-premises Oracle to Aurora MySQL?

Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, heterogeneous migration is possible. Not sure about Aurora MySQL specifically (I would imagine so as it is a MySQL database,) but GoldenGate does support heterogeneous configurations. From Oracle:

> You can use the following supported heterogeneous databases with
>   Oracle GoldenGate.
>
> DB2 LUW
>
> DB2 for i
>
> DB2 for z/OS
>
> MySQL
>
> SQL Server
>
> Teradata

More information can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/c1230/gg-winux/GGHDB/12.3-what-is-oracle-goldengate-heterogeneous-databases.htm#GGHDB-GUID-08EAC588-F76C-4E37-BEBA-0DC57B98CA46

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Please allow me to dig this deeper.  
I've read the document but it doesn't really say which version of GoldenGate should be installed on where, if I'm not missing anything.

Comment: [This document](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/goldengate/11g/GGS_Sect_Config_WinUX_ORA_to_WinUX_MSQ.pdf) says " the GoldenGate application must be installed on both the source and target systems". Does this mean A) Oracle GoldenGate 18.1.0.0.0 for Oracle on Linux x86-64 on the source and the target, B) Oracle GoldenGate 18.1.0.0.0 for MySQL on Linux x86-64 (64 MB) on the source and the target, or C) Oracle GoldenGate 18.1.0.0.0 for Oracle on Linux x86-64 on the source and Oracle GoldenGate 18.1.0.0.0 for MySQL on Linux x86-64 (64 MB)  on the target?

Comment: I would wager that it means C), but you should really contact Oracle or an Oracle certified vendor to get the ball rolling on your technical requirements. While it's absolutely possible to set something like this up without a support contract, it will be in your best interest to have one if you are working with GoldenGate in any major capacity, especially if production systems are in the equation.

Comment: Thank you again for your suggestion. Personally, I too think C) is the bet but we will contact an Oracle support to clear things out. I will post their answer when I get it, for the sake of anyone who needs it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually build your hub on a linux machine, you can install two (2) GoldenGate Homes (one for Oracle and one for MySQL).  Then you can link them together and have the extract datapump (classic)/distroservice (microservices) move the trailfiles where the MySQL setup can apply from.

Answer (score 0):

I've confirmed with Oracle Support that in order to migrate data from an Oracle database to a MySQL database, you have to install GoldenGate for Oracle on the target database and GoldenGate for MySQL on the target database.

Comment: This is not related by no means to April's Fool by the way :)